# Python: Using Pyscreenshot image to get RGB values (Linux)

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm on python 3.5 on a Ubuntu machine. I'm writing a script where I want to grab the screen and search for certain pixel colors in the image.
Since it's not windows, PIL.ImageGrab doesn't work and after some research I started using pyscreenshot.

The following works:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox(1,1,100,100))
```

Now my problem is that the type of im is PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile which doesn't have the method .getpixel like PIL.Image does. 
While I could save it to a file and load it again with PIL that seems super ugly and not efficient. How do I make a PIL.Image out of this?

I thought something along the lines of

```
im = Image.new(ImageGrab.grab(bbox(1,1,100,100)))
```

but that's obviously not it ;)

(Sidenote: If there are other/easier ways than pyscreenshot to get screenshots on Ubuntu, that's fine too)

Comment: Have no experience with `pyscreenshot`, but I like `pyautogui` to do screenshots with Linux. I think, one of its dependencies is actually `PIL`. You can easily do screenshots using `img = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0,0, 300, 400))`. And there is also a nice built-in function called `LocateOnScreen`, see [here](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html).

Comment: yes, that worked, thanks! :)